# Is there a way to control the order of Stripes Framework error messages?

Tags: java, stripes

It appears that the Stripes Framework ValidationErrors object is based on a HashMap.  Short of re-implementing my own errors object based on a LinkedHashMap, is there any way to control the order that the errors appear at the top of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<stripes:errors>
 <stripes:errors-header><div class="errorHeader">Validation Errors</div>     
 <ul></stripes:errors-header>
 <li><stripes:individual-error/></li>
 <li><stripes:another-individual-error/></li>
 <stripes:errors-footer></ul></stripes:errors-footer>
</stripes:errors>
```

Check this page:http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/taglib/

Or you can implement a ValidationErrorHandler